# What force do the armed guards guarding the Crew-1 crew belong to?

Tags: nasa, launch-site, military, kennedy-space-center, security

In the comments to the question [Why were the SpaceX Crew-1 astronauts backed up by guards with automatic weapons?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48572/6156), the question was raised [what force the guards in the photo belong to](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48572/why-were-the-spacex-crew-1-astronauts-backed-up-by-guards-with-automatic-weapons/48591?noredirect=1#comment157064_48572).

In particular, [NASA KSC has their own SWAT team](https://nasa.gov/returntoflight/main/swat_feature.html), so it stands to reason that the guards would be part of that team.

Are the armed (para-)military guards that accompanied the Crew-1 astronauts part of NASA KSC's SWAT team? And if not, which team and/or force do they belong to?

[image: Armed guards with an armed personnel carrier vehicle in the background behind the Crew-1 astronauts]

Comment: It's really hard to tell, the pictures I found from the NASA KSC Emergency Response Team, showed some sort of identification on the side of the vehicles and the right arm, but in this picture most of those areas is blocked from view.

Comment: What armed guards?  *Update:* I just found them – they're so hard to spot with that forest camouflage!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really definitive, but max zoom in on the picture [here](https://images.nasa.gov/details-NHQ202011150010)

[image]

shows an individual in the camo uniform exiting a KSC security forces vehicle

[image]

as shown [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/148487539@N08/37408954492/)

[image]