# What would have prevented a person from firing a rifle at the space shuttle during launch?

Tags: space-shuttle, security

I am plotting a story set in the early 2000s in which a terrorist shoots a high-powered rifle at a space shuttle as it is about to launch.

I have in mind that he would be located in the swamp to the north west of Launch Complex 39B.

What security or natural hazards existed to prevent him from simply walking to his shooting position from Merritt Island National Wildlife Refuge?

What other measures were (and probably still are) in place to prevent this scenario from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18023/6944 (I didn't vote to close because it would insta-close and I dislike that).

Comment: What do you have in mind for a suggested shooting location (googlemaps pin?)

Comment: @OrganicMarble thanks for the link, I didn't find that one. Some very useful info but not everything I was looking for,

Comment: @DanielChisholm Roughly https://maps.app.goo.gl/urrKYsyYzCDQ7itt5 - needs to be within 2km of pad

Comment: I don't think I can put together a full answer, but among other things, the [NASA Emergency Response Team](https://www.americanspecialops.com/photos/law-enforcement/nasa-swat.php)

Comment: Largely it's prevented by anyone getting that close.  A full auto .50 cal with incendiary, tracer rounds certainly disrupt the flight, not sure about making it explode.  But it'd have to be right at launch, because not long into the flight it would be traveling faster than the bullets at the muzzle, and they'd only get slower the higher they went.

Comment: Security deterrence would be thermal imaging cameras and likely other measures that are not publicly disclosed. One obvious natural hazard is the alligators which are plentiful at KSC and inhabit pretty much all of the water areas that an intruder would probably pass through or near as they try and avoid detection. Note that the pond in between pads 39A and 39B is named "Gator Hole", and the runway where the Shuttle landed is often referred to as the "Gator Tanning Facility.

Comment: In addition to the "lone gunman" question, see answers and comments at [Why were the SpaceX Crew-1 astronauts backed up by guards with automatic weapons?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48572/12102) including the reference to the [KSC Swat Team](https://www.nasa.gov/?search=swat) See also the circa 2000 photos in this answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48573/12102

Comment: @OrganicMarble I think this is a different question as it's about prevention as opposed to vulnerability.